# How to render Matplotlib plots with TEX code in Cyrillic

Tags: matplotlib, tex

I'm trying to understand how to plot figures with Cyrillic text in the legend.

It seems that axes display TeX characters but text in the legend is using the default font. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("pgf")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256)
y = []
for i in range(-100, 100):
    y += [np.cos(x + i)]


plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xticks([-10, 0, 10])
plt.yticks()
plt.plot(x, y[0], color = 'red', linewidth = 2.5, linestyle = '-', label = 'style1')
plt.plot(x, y[1], color = 'blue', linewidth = 3, linestyle = '-', label = 'style2')
plt.legend()
```

Changing the label of the first (the red) line to something in cyrillic:

```
plt.plot(x, y[0], color = 'red', linewidth = 2.5, linestyle = '-', label = 'стил1')
```

gives the following error:

Error in callback .post_execute at 0x00000202EDCA3AF8> (for post_execute):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    303                                              cwd=self.texcache,
--> 304                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    305         except FileNotFoundError as exc:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    410     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 411                **kwargs).stdout
    412 

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    511             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 512                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    513     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', 'C:\\Users\\Victor\\.matplotlib\\tex.cache\\b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in post_execute()
    107             def post_execute():
    108                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
--> 109                     draw_all()
    110 
    111             # IPython >= 2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_pylab_helpers.py in draw_all(cls, force)
    126         for f_mgr in cls.get_all_fig_managers():
    127             if force or f_mgr.canvas.figure.stale:
--> 128                 f_mgr.canvas.draw_idle()
    129 
    130 atexit.register(Gcf.destroy_all)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in draw_idle(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1914         if not self._is_idle_drawing:
   1915             with self._idle_draw_cntx():
-> 1916                 self.draw(*args, **kwargs)
   1917 
   1918     def draw_cursor(self, event):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    386         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    387         with RendererAgg.lock:
--> 388             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    389             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
    390             # don't forget to call the superclass.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1707             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1708             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1709                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1710 
   1711             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2645             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2646 
-> 2647         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2648 
   2649         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py in draw(self, renderer)
    656         # update the location and size of the legend. This needs to
    657         # be done in any case to clip the figure right.
--> 658         bbox = self._legend_box.get_window_extent(renderer)
    659         self.legendPatch.set_bounds(bbox.x0, bbox.y0,
    660                                     bbox.width, bbox.height)
```

...

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    284     def get_extent(self, renderer):
    285         """Return a tuple ``width, height, xdescent, ydescent`` of the box."""
--> 286         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    287         return w, h, xd, yd
    288 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    284     def get_extent(self, renderer):
    285         """Return a tuple ``width, height, xdescent, ydescent`` of the box."""
--> 286         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    287         return w, h, xd, yd
    288 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    875             "lp", self._text._fontproperties, ismath=False)
    876 
--> 877         bbox, info, d = self._text._get_layout(renderer)
    878         w, h = bbox.width, bbox.height
    879 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    296             if clean_line:
    297                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 298                     clean_line, self._fontproperties, ismath=ismath)
    299             else:
    300                 w = h = d = 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    199             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
    200             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 201                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    202             return w, h, d
    203 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    446         else:
    447             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 448             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    449             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    450                 page, = dvi

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    336                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    337                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
--> 338                      texfile], tex)
    339             for fname in glob.glob(basefile + '*'):
    340                 if not fname.endswith(('dvi', 'tex')):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    315                     prog=command[0],
    316                     tex=tex.encode('unicode_escape'),
--> 317                     exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8'))) from exc
    318         _log.debug(report)
    319         return report

RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'\\u0441\\u0442\\u0438\\u043b1'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/Victor/.matplotlib/tex.cache/b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character с (U+0441)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily с
                                                 тил1}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.log.


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    303                                              cwd=self.texcache,
--> 304                                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    305         except FileNotFoundError as exc:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    410     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 411                **kwargs).stdout
    412 

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    511             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 512                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    513     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', 'C:\\Users\\Victor\\.matplotlib\\tex.cache\\b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2063                         orientation=orientation,
   2064                         dryrun=True,
-> 2065                         **kwargs)
   2066                     renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2067                     bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, metadata, pil_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    525 
    526         else:
--> 527             FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    528             renderer = self.get_renderer()
    529             with cbook._setattr_cm(renderer, dpi=self.figure.dpi), \

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    386         self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
    387         with RendererAgg.lock:
--> 388             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    389             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
    390             # don't forget to call the superclass.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1707             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1708             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1709                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1710 
   1711             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2645             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2646 
-> 2647         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2648 
   2649         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    133     if not_composite or not has_images:
    134         for a in artists:
--> 135             a.draw(renderer)
    136     else:
    137         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py in draw(self, renderer)
    656         # update the location and size of the legend. This needs to
    657         # be done in any case to clip the figure right.
--> 658         bbox = self._legend_box.get_window_extent(renderer)
    659         self.legendPatch.set_bounds(bbox.x0, bbox.y0,
    660                                     bbox.width, bbox.height)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer)
    289     def get_window_extent(self, renderer):
    290         """Return the bounding box (`.Bbox`) in display space."""
--> 291         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    292         px, py = self.get_offset(w, h, xd, yd, renderer)
    293         return mtransforms.Bbox.from_bounds(px - xd, py - yd, w, h)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    284     def get_extent(self, renderer):
    285         """Return a tuple ``width, height, xdescent, ydescent`` of the box."""
--> 286         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    287         return w, h, xd, yd
    288 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    284     def get_extent(self, renderer):
    285         """Return a tuple ``width, height, xdescent, ydescent`` of the box."""
--> 286         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    287         return w, h, xd, yd
    288 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    417 
    418         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 419                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    420         whd_list = [(w, h, xd, (h - yd)) for w, h, xd, yd in whd_list]
    421 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    284     def get_extent(self, renderer):
    285         """Return a tuple ``width, height, xdescent, ydescent`` of the box."""
--> 286         w, h, xd, yd, offsets = self.get_extent_offsets(renderer)
    287         return w, h, xd, yd
    288 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent_offsets(self, renderer)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    491 
    492         whd_list = [c.get_extent(renderer)
--> 493                     for c in self.get_visible_children()]
    494 
    495         if not whd_list:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py in get_extent(self, renderer)
    875             "lp", self._text._fontproperties, ismath=False)
    876 
--> 877         bbox, info, d = self._text._get_layout(renderer)
    878         w, h = bbox.width, bbox.height
    879 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    296             if clean_line:
    297                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 298                     clean_line, self._fontproperties, ismath=ismath)
    299             else:
    300                 w = h = d = 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    199             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
    200             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 201                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    202             return w, h, d
    203 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    446         else:
    447             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 448             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    449             with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
    450                 page, = dvi

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    336                 self._run_checked_subprocess(
    337                     ["latex", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "--halt-on-error",
--> 338                      texfile], tex)
    339             for fname in glob.glob(basefile + '*'):
    340                 if not fname.endswith(('dvi', 'tex')):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py in _run_checked_subprocess(self, command, tex)
    315                     prog=command[0],
    316                     tex=tex.encode('unicode_escape'),
--> 317                     exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8'))) from exc
    318         _log.debug(report)
    319         return report

RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'\\u0441\\u0442\\u0438\\u043b1'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/Victor/.matplotlib/tex.cache/b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))

Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.

) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character с (U+0441)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \fontsize{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily с
                                                 тил1}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on b6f49bb15be8eba85bb671cfafccfb49.log.
```

Solving this is important for me because I plan to redo a whole project, written using R (a book) in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell tex that you would like to display some Russian.

[image]

```
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('text.latex',unicode=True)
rc('text.latex',preamble=r'\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}')
rc('text.latex',preamble=r'\usepackage[russian]{babel}')

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256)
y = []
for i in range(-100, 100):
    y += [np.cos(x + i)]


plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xticks([-10, 0, 10])
plt.yticks()
plt.plot(x, y[0], color = 'red', linewidth = 2.5, linestyle = '-', label = 'стил1')
plt.plot(x, y[1], color = 'blue', linewidth = 3, linestyle = '-', label = 'style2')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Since  `rc('text', usetex=True)` gives a `The text.latex.unicode rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.0 and will be removed in 3.2.` warning, it seems it is not needed.